# Как избавиться от сообщения "Some of the properties associated with the solution coundn't be read"?

Tags: visual-studio

При открытии некоторых решений из-под контроля версий, с которыми производились действия по добавлению и удалению проектов, иногда Студия при загрузке выдаёт такое сообщение.

Как поправлять файл решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно открыть файл решения solution.sln и отредактировать его, а именно:

- найти секцию GlobalSection
- сопоставить ее содержимое с реальным состоянием проекта, особое внимание уделить атрибуту SccNumberOfProjects.
- если есть несоответствие (например, повторы секции либо неверное количество проектов), то ненужное удалить.

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rjohri/some-of-the-properties-associated-with-the-solution-could-not-be-read).